# Reducing a size of a binary file

Tags: c

I have this text file:

```
1000000 2 3
1
```

I have a plan to read each byte and save it to `int array`.

I will save space as `-20` and new line as `-10`.

Then, I would like to save this array to binary file, but I would like to reduce a size of this file as much as I can.

Is this technique good?

```
#define MAX_CHAR_VALUE    127
#define BUFFER_LENGTH     8

int buffer[BUFFER_LENGTH] = {1, -20, 2, -20, 3, -10, 1, -10};
for (int i = 0; i < BUFFER_LENGTH; ++i) {
    if (buffer[i] > MAX_CHAR_VALUE) {
        fwrite(&(buffer[i]), sizeof(int), 1, file);
    } else {
        fwrite(&(buffer[i]), sizeof(char), 1, file);
    }
}
```

The values in the text file can be greater than `char (1 byte)`, but not greater than `int (4 bytes)`, that is why I save these values into `int array`.

Comment: When you try to read the file, you won't know whether a byte is a single byte or the first byte of a 4-byte number.

Comment: Maybe try `struct IntChar { int value; char separator; };`?

Comment: The original file will be smaller than even the "reduced size" file.

Comment: Yeah, but I will convert the binary file back to the text file, so I can parse it, cannot I?

Comment: @WeatherVane Not in any case. What if I have 1000000, it will be 7 bytes in the text file and just 1 byte in the binary file.

Comment: `int` should occupy 4 bytes in most computers nowadays :-)

Comment: In that case you should post an example that does not use all single-digit values. And unless `1000000` is binary, it won't be a single byte.

Answer (score 1):

The technique of changing the values of the received bytes into their negative values will not help on compressing your file.  I think you need to read a good reference (or an implementation) of a compression algorithm.  You can for example compress it with the run-length-encoding technique, that consists in using a sequence of bytes to indicate repetition of a character and how many times is the character repeated.  If you are to convert for example only ascii (7bit) text, you can use the eight bit to indicate a run-length-encoding code and use the rest of bits to indicate the actual number of repetitions of the character following the code.  E.g. your code has the second character repeated six times... so you can compress your file by inserting after the first `1` a byte 0x86 followed by a single `0`, and on decompressing you'll see that there's a decompression code (because the highest bit is set) and use the other seven bits `0000110` to repeat the next char six times.

This is only a simple way of compressing, and it requires that you only process with it seven bit ascii texts, but it can work.

A simple program to do this can be:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    int last_char = EOF;
    int c;
    int counter = 0;
    while((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
        if (last_char != EOF
            && c == last_char
            && counter < 127)
        {
            counter++;
            continue;
        }
        /* last_char == EOF (only for the first char)
         * || c != last_char (always that the char changes)
         * || counter >= 127 (we cannot hold more than 127 repetitions)
         * in either of these three cases we must output something.
         */
        if (last_char == EOF) {
            counter++;
            last_char = c;
            continue;
        }
        if (counter >= 3) {
            putchar(0x80 + counter);
            putchar(last_char);
            counter = 1;
            last_char = c;
            continue;
        }
        /* counter < 3 && c != last_char */
        int rep;
        for (rep = 0; rep < counter; rep++)
            putchar(last_char);
        counter = 1;
        last_char = c;
    } /* while */
    /* at end of file, we need to output what is still stored here */
    if (last_char == EOF) {
        /* empty file */
        return EXIT_SUCCESS;
    }
    if (counter >= 3) {
        putchar(0x80 + counter);
        putchar(last_char);
        return EXIT_SUCCESS;
    }
    int rep;
    for (rep = 0; rep < counter; rep++)
        putchar(last_char);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
} /* main */
```

a run of this program would be:

```
$ rle | hd
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
@@@@@@@@@@
@@@@
@@@
@@
@
00000000 : 94 40 0a 8a 40 0a 84 40 0a 83 40 0a 40 40 0a 40 : .@..@..@..@.@@.@
00000010 : 0a                                              : .
00000011
```

the output will be the sequence of these groups of bytes:

```
94 40             => 0x14 (20) repetitions of char '@'
0a                => a single '\n'
8a 40             => 0x0a (10) repetitions of char '@'
0a                => a single '\n'
84 40             => 0x04 (4) repetitions of char '@'
0a                => a single '\n'
83 40             => 0x03 (3) repetitions of char '@'
0a 40 40 0a 40 0a => the sequence '\n' '@' '@' '\n' '@' '\n'
```

But in my opinion, you had better to learn how to pipe it to `gzip` and get it compressed.

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems with this.

1. When writing the small value, `&buffer[i]` might point to the high-order byte of `buffer[i]`, not the low-order byte; it depends on whether the machine is big-endian or little-endian. On most modern machines, I think you'll end up writing the high-order byte, which is just `0`. You should change that code to:

```
    char temp = buffer[i];
    fwrite(&temp, sizeof temp, 1, file);
```

2. When you're reading the file, there's no way to know whether a byte is a small value that was written in 1 byte, or the first byte of a larger value that was written as 4 bytes. You need some way to distinguish the two formats in the file.

If you want to reduce the size of files, you're better off using a compression program or library.